keyless ssh via an intermediary computer
There are three systems: my local PC, computer A and computer B.
In order to log in to B from my local PC I have to run:
ssh -XJ user@computerA user@computerB

I have keyless ssh set up from my local PC to A and from A to B.  But when I do the above ssh -XJ it still asks for my password. How can I avoid that happening?

https://superuser.com/a/1773922/432690

From your description it sounds as if you created a key-pair on A and copied the public key to the authorized_keys on B. This isn't going to work with -J. B needs to know the key of the originating local PC, so copy the content of your local .pub file(s) to B's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.
